# Is EntityFramework required in my Models project that uses code first attributes to define models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created a seperate project and copied over my models to this project.
I referenced

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

My models are defined like:

```
 public class File
 {
        [Key]
        [Column("file_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

The error I get is:

```
The type or namespace Column could not be found ...
```

If I add a reference to EntityFramework it works fine, but I want to re-use my models project by referencing it for my Web Api Rest Client library and don't want to bring in EF for no reason.

I am using .net 4.0

Did they fix this issue (making it loosly coupled with EF) in 4.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this issue is fixed with .NET 4.5.

The Object Catalogue for the `EntityFramework.dll` of EF 5 with .NET 4.0 (also known as EF 4.4) shows all the attributes in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace that are in the EF assembly:

[image: EF 5 with .NET 4.0]

Whereas the `EntityFramework.dll` of EF 5 with .NET 4.5 does not contain those namespaces anymore:

[image: EF 5 with .NET 4.5]

The attributes have been moved into the .NET 4.5 framework assembly `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` under the same namespace they had been before in the EF assembly:

[image: DataAnnotations with .NET 4.5]

(`MinLength` and `MaxLength` are in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` as well, the total list of all attributes in there is too long for the screenshot.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to reference all of EF.  You should just be able to reference `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`.  Adding EF may just add that as a reference for you.

FYI [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute.aspx) will tell you which namespace and assembly a framework class exists in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use attributes to create metadata. The whole concept of POCO models is just about it.

The trick is to have an assembly of model classes which **do not** reference the EF. You can safely reuse this assembly in any context.

Then, in another assembly, you create your DbContext class, refrence the EF and create the metadata programatically. In EF this approach is called Code First Fluent Api.

http://codefirst.codeplex.com/

Comment: What if your model properties are named differently that your table columns? e.g. UserId in your model, and table column is user_id

Comment: That's what the Fluent API is about. If names correspond 1-1 you don't have to write any supporting code, EF will just use default conventions. In other words, no fluent configuration code - it works on defaults, any custom code - you customize mappings.